# DateTime.ParseExact fails depending on the parsed string's length

Tags: c#, datetime

This is very weird. I have the following code:

```
Assert.AreEqual(new DateTime(2000, 1, 1), DateTime.ParseExact("2000", "yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
Assert.AreEqual(new DateTime(2000, 1, 1), DateTime.ParseExact("20000705", "yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

The first line passes, the second one fails with "`System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime`".

I cannot shorten the string to be parsed to match the length of the format - it would work in this particular case, but this is part of a more generic method, and it would fail somewhere else. Any idea on why the second call fails?

[Edit] Ok, I was hoping it was parsing just as much of the input string as needed to satisfy the format.

I get a lot of strings in a lot of formats, and I have one method that accepts both and, after a bit of processing (I only get dates, so I replace "m" with "M" and "Y" with "y" and so on), I call `DateTime.ParseExact`. The reason I cannot call `DateTime.Parse` is because it doesn't allow for a format argument... I can get ddMMyyyy in one part of the program and yyyyddMM in another, there's no way for it to correctly figure it out.

[Edit 2] I guess it's my fault... I'll have to truncate the input when that issue arises. Fortunately I generally have all parts of the date in the format, this (just the year) is a rare occurence. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It failed because [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) requires the input string to match the specified format *exactly* (err, I mean *almost exactly*, per your comment below), and "20000705" does not match "yyyy".

To parse "20000705", you'll need to use a different technique - either `ParseExact` with an appropriate format string (like "yyyyMMdd"), or [`DateTime.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), which is a bit more forgiving (though also less accurate).

It looks like you're trying to extract the year from the date string - no parse method will do that for you.

Instead you should get the actual `DateTime` represented by the string - July 5th 2000 or May 7th 2000, depending on your format - and then extract the year using [`DateTime.Year`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.year%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Comment: I understand the point of the name, but it's not entirely accurate, as this works:

    Assert.AreEqual(new DateTime(2000, 7, 5), "07/05/2000".ParseDate("M/d/yyyy"));

(Where ParseDate ultimately calls DateTime.ParseExact.)

It works even though the input string has two digits per month and day, and the format only specifies one. Incidentally, this is the reason I can't cut the input string to match the length of the format string.

Comment: How strange. Maybe it's because it's also an output specifier and the designers thought it should be more tolerant when parsing input. The documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#M_Specifier) could certainly be clearer.

Answer (score 2):

It's absolutely right to fail - you've told it to expect exactly 4 characters, and then given it 8!

Options:

- Provide more format strings (e.g. "yyyyMMdd") to the call (you can specify multiple valid formats)
- Only pass in the piece of the string you expect to match the format
- Parse the string yourself

You claim that truncating the string "would fail somewhere else" - could you give more details? If you're specifying "yyyy" then presumably you know you need exactly 4 characters... do you know exactly where they'll be within the string? If so, why can't you perform the truncation?

Answer (score 0):

The highest date that the DateTime can represent is December 31st 9999.  You're asking it to understand a year greater than 9999.  You either need to specify a format matching the value you're giving it, so that it understands that just the first 4 digits is the year.  "yyyymmdd", for example.